# Autofill unknown amount of cells

Tags: excel, autofill

I'm trying to write VBA code for the equivalent of click and drag the corner of cell to the end. illustration:
[image: illustration]

I've tried several different suggestions I've found online but I am always met with errors.

Below is the line I am currently working on. But I am getting **Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error**.

```
Range("A4").Select
ActiveCell.AutoFill Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).End(xlRight).Offset(0, -1))
```

For more context here is the whole script I am working on: screenshot of whole script:
[image: screenshot of whole script] and here is the original line of script according to my own logic before I started looking for answers online:

```
Selection.Autofill Destination:=Range("A4":mylastcell_4), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

`mylastcell_4` has been declared at the top of the script (see screenshot of whole script). I've also tried changing to `"A4",mylastcell_4` but I still receive the error.

I am extremely new to VBA and have no idea where to go from here.

I've tried

```
 .Range(.Cells(4, "A"), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(3, 0)).Formula = "=concatenate(a2, a1, a3)"
```

Which is suggested in one of the answers below.  However this only gives the result if I have 5 cells in row 1.  I require more flexibility as there might be anywhere from 2 values to 500 values to work with.  [Image of results of above suggested script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDi2q.png)

I've also found that going along this route seems to destroy my next lot of concatenation that I know worked well separately - hopefully its something simple that needs altering? [Script used for next concatenation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQKFJ.png).

The ultimate goal of this exercise is to get a list of text prepared to go straight into SQL.  i.e. a b c d e  becomes 'a','b','c','d','e' all in one cell.

Answer (score 1):

The content you want to add is this formula placed in A4.

```
=concatenate(a2, a1, a3)
```

Since all three preceding rows are important to the formula, it's inferred that any of the preceding rows could be used for a 'stop' point to the right. I'll use row 1 (3 rows above) and offset down to locate the 'stop' point.

```
with worksheets("sheet1")
    ...
    .cells(4, "A").formula = "=concatenate(a2, a1, a3)"
    .range(.cells(4, "A"), .cells(1, .columns.count).end(xltoleft).offset(3, 0)).fillright
    ...
end with
```

I prefer .FillRight for this operation over .AutoFill but you can easily use this method for .AutoFill as well.

Alternately, you could have just written the formula into all four cells at once.

```
with worksheets("sheet1")
    ...
    .range(.cells(4, "A"), .cells(1, .columns.count).end(xltoleft).offset(3, 0)).formula = "=concatenate(a2, a1, a3)"
    ...
end with
```

You need to preface each Range and Cells with `.` like `.Range(...)` and `.Cells(...)` in order for your `with worksheets("sheet1")` to work properly.

In your own version, if *mylastcell_4* was set correctly, then this would likely have solved the issue.

```
.Range("A4").Autofill Destination:=.Range("A4:" & mylastcell_4.address), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

You set up a With Worksheet ... End With block then never appeared to use it.

Comment: thanks for your help.  I've gone with the second code you suggested except I see that this is hard coded for only 4 cells where as I need it to go all the way to the end which may be 4 cells, or may be 400 cells.

Comment: No, it is hard-coded for the fourth row, not four cells. `.cells(4, "A")` is A4. `.range(.cells(4, "A"), .cells(1, .columns.count).end(xltoleft).offset(3, 0))` starts at A4 and looks right as far as there are cell in row 1.

Comment: Hmm OK thats weird.  I've just added to the question with my image of what comes out when I do that.

Comment: That's because F2:H3 are blank. You are concatenating zero-length string (i.e. *nothing*) so nothing shows up for those rows.

Comment: So therefore this line isn't working then      Range("A3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = "'',"

Comment: I've tried to update this using my lastcell values that I declare at the start.  Range("A2").Select
    Range("A2", mylastcell_2).Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = "''"    But somehow this is overwriting everything in row 1 other than the last column.  I don't get why it would do this.

Comment: I had my down and across numbers mixed up in the offset.

Comment: Yay the second script you suggested along with the changing of the range of my formula arrays has worked.

Comment: I've turned the second part of my question into a new question if you are able to help me with that.  Thanks lots.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52960214/concatenate-an-unknown-number-of-cells

Comment: @N.Begg, Please!! mark this answer as accepted (a little grey mark below the voting buttons). [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). It shows other people that this question is completly solved and gives you and the person who answered credit.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of a range in VBA follows this structure:

```
Range(A1:D1) -> Range(Cells(A1), Cells(D1)) -> 

Range(Cells(row number, column number), Cells(row number, column number)) -> 

Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 4)) ... And then you can replace 1,1 & 1,4 with variables..
```

Maybe this works but I think your range might need to be modified/clarified. Is not clear what you are trying to achieve (what do you want the code to do, what is your expected result).., but this could be worth a try:

```
ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).End(xlRight).Offset(0, -1))
```

I want to encourage you, keep on learning VBA :)!!!

Comment: Hi Wizhi I've tried altering to your script but its getting the same error as I previously were getting.  I've added to the question to show my original attempt as well as a picture of what I am trying to achieve for this sentence.   What else would be useful to help you guys help me?  Thanks for your encouragement :)  In my normal corner of Stackoverflow whenever you ask a question there is one particular person who always comes through and edits little minor things within your question which makes you feel like an idiot since they constantly do it, so its nice to see it not here.