# Concatenate an unknown number of cells

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

This is a follow on question from my original question which has helped me solve the first part of my script: [Autofill unknown amount of cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52958308/autofill-unknown-amount-of-cells).

The second part of my script is to concatenate an unknown number of cells.
Using the logic from the first question I have tried to alter my script for to this `myconcatenate = ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=Concatenate("A5", mylastcell_4)"`
But it is resulting in a **syntax error.**

Originally I was given this piece of script which worked fine on its own but doesn't work when added to the bottom of my script

```
  Do
    myconcatenate = myconcatenate & ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
  Loop Until ActiveCell.Address = mylastcell_5

  Range("A5").Select
  ActiveCell.Value = myconcatenate
```

This gives a **run time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error** and will go to the very last cell on row 5 (even though I only have 5 currently occupied in Row 1) and does nothing while it passes through all the cells.  Sometimes it will do the first bit of the script (adds '', to the cell values) other times it doesn't.

Here is my full script for context: [Screenshot of full script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Oga.png)

Ultimately I am trying to get from a list of abcdedf to 'a','b','c','d','e','f', into one cell.

Ultimate goal picture: 
[image: Ultimate goal picture]  
row 5 cell D gives the ultimate answer I'm after, E5 would be **mylastcell_5**

This is my first day on VBA, and I have spent the whole day googling bits to try and answer questions but this hasn't resulted in anything for me.

**UPDATE:** I've declared mylastcell_5 which I hadn't done previously.  I'm now getting no error in the script and it is just hanging out at A5 rather than going to the very end of the page, but it's not actually concatenating.

**So I think that somehow I need to change my loop so that it is writing to row 5 but reading from row 4 ... but I don't know how to do this.**

```
Option Explicit
Sub concat()
'
' concat Macro
' 'text','text'
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+C
'
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim mylastcell_1 As String, mylastcell_2 As String, mylastcell_3 As String, mylastcell_4 As String, mylastcell_5 As String, myconcatenate As String, myconcatenate1 As String
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    mylastcell_1 = ActiveCell.Address

    Range(mylastcell_1).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    mylastcell_2 = ActiveCell.Address

    Range(mylastcell_2).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    mylastcell_3 = ActiveCell.Address

    Range(mylastcell_3).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    mylastcell_4 = ActiveCell.Address

    Range(mylastcell_4).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    mylastcell_5 = ActiveCell.Address

    myconcatenate = ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select


    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range("A2", mylastcell_2).Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = "''"
    Range("A3").Select
    Range("A3", mylastcell_3).Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = "'',"
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(R[-2]C,R[-3]C,R[-1]C)"
    Range("A4").Select
   .Range(.Cells(4, "A"), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(3, 0)).Formula = "=concatenate(a2, a1, a3)"
    Range("A5").Select

Do
        myconcatenate = myconcatenate & ActiveCell.Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

    Loop Until ActiveCell.Address = mylastcell_5

    Range("A5").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = myconcatenate




End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the full code in the screenshot. When you're done with that, add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module and fix all the compile errors. You get the 1004 because `mylastcell_5` is never defined.

Comment: which version of Excel?

Comment: @Comintern  I've updated the script and I'm no longer getting errors, but it still isn't doing anything I want it to.

Comment: @Vasily Excel version Professional Plus 2016

Comment: You forgot the part about [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52960214/edit) to include the full code instead of [a screenshot of your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374700/4088852).

Comment: textjoin is only in the 365 subscription excel rather than the version we have :/ That would be amazing if I could use it!

Comment: So what would a typical value for `mylastcell_5` be?  Remember, `.Address` returns an *absolute* cell address, i.e. `$A$1`.

Comment: @Comintern mylastcell_5 should be null.  It is the place holder to tell the concatenate when to stop.  It has been generated by looking down from the original row to find out when those values have stopped.  I've added a screenshot of this into my question.  Does this mean that I need to change the activecell to be an offest of mylastcell_1 (which does have a value) can you do this? is there another way of doing it that doesn't use .address?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you always plan to concatenate elements into a single-quote enclosed comma-delimited string, but if you do here are a couple ways to do that (I've found it useful for quickly inserting things into SQL statements, for example). One joins vertical strings (single column) and one joins horizontal strings (single row). This would be a standard worksheet function where you would enter something like `=hjoin(a1:h1)` or `=vjoin(a1:a7)`

```
Function hJoin(inRng As Range) As String
Dim c As Range
Dim outStr As String
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range(inRng.Address)


For Each c In rng.Columns
    If c.Address = rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count).Address Then
            outStr = outStr & " '" & c.Value & "'"
        Else
            outStr = outStr & " '" & c.Value & "',"
        End If
    Next c

hJoin = outStr

End Function

Function vJoin(inRng As Range) As String
Dim c As Range
Dim outStr As String
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range(inRng.Address)


For Each c In rng.Rows
    If c.Address = rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count).Address Then
         outStr = outStr & " '" & c.Value & "'"
    Else
         outStr = outStr & " '" & c.Value & "',"
    End If
Next c

vJoin = outStr

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Oxwilder, it is asking for c to be defined, what do I define it as?

Comment: When the input box comes up, did you select a range of cells you want to add to the list? You can select the range with your mouse or type a group of cells into the box.

Comment: I ended up defining c as a range which made that part happy so I could actually run the tool.  But when I copied my selection of values into the input box I got an error from Excel saying that there is a problem with the formula. I have tried to change the input box to a selection by changing it to   Range("A1").Select
 Set rng = Selection.End(xlToRight).Select.  But its not actually doing anything still.

Comment: No, you don't want to add the values. You just select the cells where the values are. Drag the mouse over the cells containing the data you want to concatenate.

Comment: I have selected the values and it looks like it does something, but there is no output at all.

Comment: @N.Begg Adapted function to your issue. Try these instead.